# << search results breaks after clicking next possible job

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The << search results on a job listing page breaks after you look at another job within the search.  Steps to reproduce:

1. Do a search for **Permanent** jobs
2. Click Search
3. Select a result
4. When you are looking at a job there is three links at the top << search results, < Another Job,  Another Job >.
5. Click Another Job>
6. Now click search results

It no longer takes you to the search results page.  In fact, it keeps reiterating the same jobs you looked at.

The links are broken at the top and the bottom of the job listing page.

Here's a video showing the issue: http://screencast.com/t/xzmJokzL3I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This ended up being a regression introduced by a bugfix to another part of job search. Fun! Fixed now.